# Query - Converting Text to DateTime

Tags: ms-access

This is within Access... I am having an issue converting two time stamps to DateTime within my Query so I can use the DateDiff function to find the difference between the two.

I just do not know which formula is the best to accomplish what I need.

The format of the time stamps comes out to 2015-01-06 09:01:54.0000000

So I need something to convert this to an actual date and be able to subtract it from the other value to find the time between each.

Also - If DateDiff is not the best way to go about doing this, please advise that as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried CDate()

Comment: You need to lose those zeros before CDate, eg Sub DateStuff()
strDate = Mid("2015-01-06 09:01:54.0000000", 1, 19)
dteDate = CDate(strDate)
Debug.Print DateDiff("y", Date, dteDate)
End Sub See also https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f

Comment: Fionnuala - Thank you... this definitely helped. After I have the results I want, I want to make sure the difference of the times is stored as a number so I can add and subtract easily... how would I go about doing that? I have a field that has all the differences stored in Seconds... I have converted those seconds to a format of hh.mm.ss, but if I want to add those and total them, should I just leave it as seconds and convert the total? Or can I display hh.mm.ss as a number? Right now its just Formatted as hh.mm.ss.

Comment: I expect the converted value is a string not a number. Do calc with seconds.